# Force decimal point in formatted string to stay in same position

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am trying to format a `double` that represents a value from `-12.00V` to `12.00V`.

I am having a hard time formatting it so that the string produces always has the decimal point in the middle.

The `String.Format()` arguments (`"{0:0.00V}"`) I use produces 4 "types" of numbers

```
0.00V
00.00V
-0.00V
-00.00V
```

I would like a way to make all of the "types" appear like so

```
  0.00V
 00.00V
 -0.00V
-00.00V
```

So that all of the decimal places always line up with each other no matter the value. Is this possible with `.Format()`? I know there is the alignment argument but that just aligns the entire string to the left or right and not the string within its own "space".

Comment: untested but `stringName.PadLeft(" ", 6)` should work

Comment: {0,6:0.00V} should do the trick

Comment: Mmm, depends what you are trying to achieve. Based on the font used simply using spaces would not work. What you really want is "Right-Aligned" and as this seems like a UI question I would suggest that the control (label / textbox) has an option for alignment. So, format as you have now but set the control's alignment to "Right". If you are using a console font then the above suggestions are a good start.

Comment: @qqbenq Almost, works if no tens digit. // ATSayse, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user1596244, yeah, 6 is a little bit smaller than 7, but I never was too good with numbers, sorry :)

Comment: Your first example is the default result for "Left" "TextAlign", where as your second example (your preferred way) is the default result for "Righ" "TextAlign". Why do you need the space, I still can't understand. (Yes, I've read your last sentence in the question.)

Comment: With variable width fonts the decimal place will move even when the text is aligned to the right. I wanted a way in which to force the decimal point to stay put. (Though, I guess you can't really do it without fixed-width fonts). So in the end I ended up using a fixed-width font and using right align/DStanleys answer, which are basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To right-align, add a width specifier:

```
"{0,8:0.00V}"
```

that will give you room for the `V`, two decimals, a decimal point, two significant digits to the left, a sign, and a leading space (or three significant digits and no leading space).

Comment: This works well enough, thanks! The decimal moves just a little between a single to double digit number.

Comment: Are you looking in a control?  If the control uses a variable-width font then there's no easy way to align _exactly_ on the decimal

Comment: Yeah in a control. I assume I also have a variable width font then too.

Comment: Probably.  depending on the control you can try to change to a fixed-width font like Consolas or Courier

Comment: I changed to Courier and it actually looks a bit nicer (for being a voltage readout)!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PadLeft` function as follows: `[YourStringVariable].PadLeft(6)` ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))